# Need a script to delete certain type of files in a folder based on conditions

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript, cmd, onenote

I am having some issues with OneNote overpopulating the drive with .onetoc2 files. I need a script or cmd command that deletes these files only if the folder that it's contained in does not have a .one file. I need this run for the entire directory.

I have a delete prompt that deletes all the files but I don't know how to get the conditional aspect of it accomplished.

```
DEL /S /Q c:\Folders \*.onetoc2
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this could work in powershell

```
$folder
if (!(dir $folder *.one)) {
    dir $folder *.onetoc2 | % {del $_.FullName -WhatIf}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /b "c:\folder\*.onetoc2"') do if not exist "%~dpA%~nA.one" echo del "%A"
```

Use `%%A` in batch. Remove the echo statement to allow it to delete.

Comment: `if not exist "%~dpnA.one"` suffices; you should point out that also for the `~` parts of the `%A` variable, the `%` need to be doubled when the code is used in a batch file...